# HTML5 media attribute question

Tags: html

What keywords can I use for in the media attribute. I know I can use the keyword `not` but what others are there if any? If there are more what is the complete list of keywords available?

Answer (score 0):

The specification will tell you what is allowed. Unfortunately, you have to search for the media attributes: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

Comment: I read this a while back and I still couldn't find what I was looking for at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use w3schools to look it up,
i found this when i looked at this page: 
[w3shools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)
it has a neat table displaying it.
they also have many other tables, i use it a lot!